# Python - requests fail silently

Tags: python-requests

```
import requests
```

is working properly for all my requests, like so:

```
url = 'http://www.stackoverflow.com'
response = requests.get(url)
```

bur the following `url` does not return any results:

```
url = 'http://www.billboard.com'
response = requests.get(url)
```

it stalls and **fails silently**, returning nothing.

how do I force `requests` into throwing me an exception response, 
so I can know if I'm being blacklisted or else?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Requests won't raise an exception for a bad HTTP response, but you could use `raise_for_status` to raise a `HTTPError` exception manually, example:

```
response = requests.get(url)

response.raise_for_status()
```

Another option is `status_code`, which holds the HTTP code.

```
response = requests.get(url)

if response.status_code != 200:
    print('HTTP', response.status_code)
else: 
    print(response.text)
```

If a site returns HTTP 200 for bad requests, but has an error message in the response body or has no body, you'll have to check the response content.

```
error_message = 'Nothing found'
response = requests.get(url)

if error_message in response.text or not response.text:
    print('Bad response')
else: 
    print(response.text)
```

If a site takes too long to respond you could set a maximum timeout for the request. If the site won't respond in that time a `ReadTimeout` exception will be raised.

```
try:
    response = requests.get(url, timeout=5)
except requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout:
    print('Request timed out')
else:
    print(response.text)
```

Comment: thank you. but none of the options above return anything. it waits and waits, forever. I'm sure I've been blocked or blacklisted, because when I changed internet connection (ip), it ran smoothly. so if you edit your answer with a workaround such as the usage of a rotating agent, I'll accept that as an answer.

Comment: If the site is blocking your ip changing User-Agent won't help. Also, most tor exits are blacklisted, so i wouldn't trust tor. If you don't have a private proxy you can find some free proxies here: [free-proxy-list.net](https://free-proxy-list.net/) and in similar websites, but keep in mind that they are also very unreliable.

Comment: curious product. it is named `'free', but at U$ 8 a month`. thanks for the link, anyway. will look into this solution.

Comment: wow. it actually returned response content (also with `response.content`) after the elapsed timeout. what kind of magic was that?

Comment: yes, it returned url, both with `reponse.text` and `response.content`, after a while. maybe restriction was due to the speed the page was being hit, I dont know. but it is working now.

Comment: `if str(response.status_code)[0] != 2:
             response.raise_for_status()`

Answer (score 0):

with:

```
import requesocks

#Initialize a new wrapped requests object
session = requesocks.session()

#Use Tor for both HTTP and HTTPS
session.proxies = {'http': 'socks5://localhost:9050', 
                   'https': 'socks5://localhost:9050'}

#fetch a page that shows your IP address
response = session.get('https://www.billboard.com')

print(response.text)
```

I was able to get:

```
    raise ConnectionError(e)
requesocks.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.billboard.com', port=None): Max retries exceeded with url: https://www.billboard.com/
```